# plocate updatedb /var/lib/plocate/: Is a directory error

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, locate

> plocate is a locate(1) based on posting lists, giving much faster searches
> on a much smaller index. It is a drop-in replacement for mlocate in nearly
> all aspects, and is fast on SSDs and non-SSDs alike.

But I'm having problem using it ***under WSL1***.

```bash
$ plocate java
/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db: No such file or directory

$ sudo updatedb
/var/lib/plocate/: Is a directory

$ updatedb.plocate
/var/lib/plocate/: Is a directory

$ apt-cache policy plocate
plocate:
  Installed: 1.1.8-2+deb11u1
  Candidate: 1.1.8-2+deb11u1
  Version table:
     1.1.13-1~bpo11+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.1.8-2+deb11u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if your kernel is very old (older than what is supported in bullseye), or you are using something pretending imperfectly to be the Linux kernel (like WSL1). A workaround was put in place in plocate 1.1.12.

Answer (score 4):

You have to update a database for plocate, I fixed the problem using:

```
sudo updatedb.plocate
```

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, but you need to read people's question carefully next time -- the problem you "fixed" is a total different one than the OP.

Comment: Sorry! I will be more careful next time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update to 1.1.13-1~bpo11+1 fixed the problem:

`sudo apt install -y plocate -t bullseye-backports`